# DCEL operations on quad-edges, Twin, Next, and Prev

Tags: computational-geometry, doubly-connected-edge-list

Suppose I have a quad-edge data-structure, and I want to be able to perform the operations of DCEL (`twin`, `next`, `prev`) on the quad-edge data structure. Let the current edge I am operating on be `e`. I know that `e.twin` would simply be `e.rot.rot`. I am just unsure about `next` and `prev`.

(Quad-Edge visualization given below.)

[image: Quad Edge Visualization]

`next` should be equivalent to `Lnext` in the picture. Thus I tried to derive it and got `e.rot.rot.rot.Onext.rot`. `prev` should be equivalent to `Lprev`, which is the twin of `Onext`, i.e. `e.Onext.rot.rot`.

Is this correct? I am using quad-edges to prove properties on half-edges, so I want to make sure I got the basics correct before I proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you took these diagrams from [this CMU publication](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/andrew/scs/cs/15-463/2001/pub/src/a2/quadedge.html). This publication also refers to the C++ header `cell/edge.hh`, describing basic and derived operations on edges.

So, according to this header, operations `Rot`, `InvRot`, `Sym` and `Onext` are considered basic ones, and all the other operations - derived ones. The DCEL operations `next` and `prev` are equivalent to quad-edge operations `Lnext` and `Lprev`, which are defined in this header as inline functions (I'm dropping the C++ syntax and keeping the meaning):

```
e.Lnext = e.InvRot.Onext.Rot
e.Lprev = e.Onext.Sym
```

So, your formulas look correct, with slightly overused operation `Rot`.